# AlertDialog styling - how to change style (color) of title, message, etc

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-theme, android-styles

I've breaking my head over this quite a bit. What I need to do is, change the style of all `AlertDialog`s in my android application - dialog background needs to be white-ish, and text needs to be black-ish. I tried creating a lot of styles, themes, and applying from the code, manifest, etc, but no success, with regard to the text colors inside the `AlertDialog`. Right now, I have the simplest of codes, set like this:

Manifest:

> ```
> <application
>     android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
>     android:label="@string/app_name"
>     android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
> ```

styles.xml:

> ```
> <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
>     <item name="android:alertDialogStyle">@style/DialogStyle</item>
> </style>
>
> <style name="DialogStyle" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
>     <!-- changing these background stuff works fine -->
>     <item name="android:bottomBright">@android:color/white</item>
>     <item name="android:bottomDark">@android:color/white</item>
>     <item name="android:bottomMedium">@drawable/dialog_footer_bg</item>
>     <item name="android:centerBright">@android:color/white</item>
>     <item name="android:centerDark">@drawable/dialog_body_bg</item>
>     <item name="android:centerMedium">@android:color/white</item>
>     <item name="android:fullBright">@color/orange</item>
>     <item name="android:fullDark">@color/orange</item>
>     <item name="android:topBright">@color/green</item>
>     <item name="android:topDark">@drawable/dialog_header_bg</item>
> ```

The items listed below don't work (please read the comments I've put above each element):

> ```
>     <!-- panelBackground is not getting set to null, there is something squarish around it -->
>     <item name="android:panelBackground">@null</item>
>
>     <!-- Setting this textColor doesn't seem to have any effect at all. Messages, title, button text color, whatever; nothing changes. -->
>     <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
>
>     <!-- Also tried with textAppearance, as follows. Didn't work -->
>     <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textColorPrimaryInverse</item>
>
>     <!-- Also tried changing textAppearancePrimary, to no avail -->
>     <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#000000</item>
>
>     <!-- Also need to change the dialog title text, tried it as follows, dint work: -->
>     <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@style/DialogWindowTitle</item>
> </style>
> ```

The DialogWindowTitle is defined as follows:

> ```
> <style name="DialogWindowTitle">
>     <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceMediumInverse</item>
> </style>
> ```

So none of these is working. Can anyone tell me what I could be doing wrong, and how can I:

1. Change text color for messages (content text)
2. Change title text color
3. Remove the
   panel background

Note: I need to support API 8 (2.2) upwards. Also, I've went through most of the related question here, and google groups, but can't figure out, though I have a feeling its right under my nose!

Edit: adding screenshot:

[image: AlertDialog not themed as expected]

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of how it currently looks?

Comment: @Ahmad: Screenshot added

Comment: i wanna know how you got those background colors to change.  using this exact same code, i cannot replicate a colored AlertDialog against API level 9.  did you apply the theme or style some special way?  what is your target and min sdk level set to?

Comment: weird... somehow i got it working and i have no idea how.  thanks a lot for this post, i was scratching my head for hours on end over this.  for anyone searching, this question/answer is the definitive way to customize AlertDialogs in Android API levels < 11.

Comment: ...but for some reason, if i run this code on any device running Android >= 3.0, the dialog colors do not change.  so it seems this has to be handled two different ways for >2.3.3 and <2.3.3... maybe in separate APKs?  what a mess...  they really screwed this up between Android versions.

Comment: @moonlightcheese I think the properties under DialogStyle are only for non-fragment-based dialogs, that's why they wouldn't work on post honeycomb devices. You don't need several apks, but just to define additional properties for the fragment-based dialogs. They won't bother each other, and if they would, you can always use resource qualifiers. Have a look to [Dadou's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24560017/467900) to see new Dialog's themes and related styles.

Answer (score 50):

You need to define a Theme for your AlertDialog and reference it in your Activity's theme. The attribute is `alertDialogTheme` and not `alertDialogStyle`. Like this:

```
<style name="Theme.YourTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
    ...
    <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/YourAlertDialogTheme</item>
</style>

<style name="YourAlertDialogTheme">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMajor">@android:dimen/dialog_min_width_major</item>
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMinor">@android:dimen/dialog_min_width_minor</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">...</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearanceMedium">...</item>
    <item name="android:borderlessButtonStyle">...</item>
    <item name="android:buttonBarStyle">...</item>
</style>
```

You'll be able to change color and text appearance for the title, the message and you'll have some control on the background of each area. I wrote a [blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20200214041924/http://blog.supenta.com/2014/07/02/how-to-style-alertdialogs-like-a-pro/) detailing the steps to style an AlertDialog.

Comment: blog post got me exactly what I needed. I shouldve been using android:textColorPrimary and android:textColorAlertDialogListItem to style the contents of my dialog.

Comment: alertDialogTheme is api11

Comment: `alertDialogTheme `means everything else.

Comment: setting `android:textAppearanceMedium` doesn't work for me when using app compat alert dialog: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35179537/android-message-font-size-in-alertdialog-through-styles

Comment: that's correct using Material theme you cannot use `android:textAppearanceMedium` to change the content style, see this thread for a workaround http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35179537/android-message-font-size-in-alertdialog-through-styles/36749547#36749547

Comment: But how to change font typeface of buttons?

Answer (score 14):

**Remove the panel background**

```
 <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/transparent_color</item> 
 <color name="transparent_color">#00000000</color>
```

This is Mystyle:

```
 <style name="ThemeDialogCustom">
    <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/transparent_color</item>
    <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">stateUnspecified|adjustPan</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
</style>
```

Which i have added to  the constructor.

**Add textColor :**

```
<item name="android:textColor">#ff0000</item>
```

Comment: `name="android:textColor"` line worked for me. 
      `<item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/profileWhite</item>` was editing only text message color.

Answer (score 10):

Here's my Code to theme the alert dialog box:

```
<style name="alertDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="android:background">@color/light_button_text_color</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextColor" tools:targetApi="m">@android:color/black</item>
</style>
```

Place this code in styles.xml.
In your java apply this theme as:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.alertDialog);
```

[Output of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QMEc.png)

Answer (score 9):

You have to add the style to the constructor of the dialog

```
builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.DialogStyle);
```

Comment: note that use of this constructor is only available in API level 11+

Comment: You're right, i looked for a solution several days without solution. So I use a basic Dialog with my custom view in xml. Like this  `final ContextThemeWrapper l_contextThemeWrapper = new ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.myDialogStyle );             dialog = new Dialog(l_contextThemeWrapper);
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);`

Answer (score 5):

I changed color programmatically in this way :

```
var builder = new AlertDialog.Builder (this);
...
...
...
var dialog = builder.Show ();
int textColorId = Resources.GetIdentifier ("alertTitle", "id", "android");
TextView textColor = dialog.FindViewById<TextView> (textColorId);
textColor?.SetTextColor (Color.DarkRed);
```

as alertTitle, you can change other data by this way (next example is for titleDivider):

```
int titleDividerId = Resources.GetIdentifier ("titleDivider", "id", "android");
View titleDivider = dialog.FindViewById (titleDividerId);
titleDivider?.SetBackgroundColor (Color.Red);
```

this is in C#, but in java it is the same.

Comment: This is the java version of the code - `int textColorId = getResources().getIdentifier("alertMessage", "id", "android");
                    TextView textColor = (TextView) alertDialog.findViewById(textColorId);
                    if (textColor != null) {
                        textColor.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                    }`

Answer (score 3):

It depends how much you want to customize the alert dialog. I have different steps in order to customize the alert dialog. Please visit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33439849/5475941

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Building on @general03's answer, you can use Android's built-in style to customize the dialog quickly. You can find the dialog themes under `android.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault_Dialogxxx`.

For example:

```
builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, android.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault_Dialog_MinWidth);
builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, android.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault_Dialog_NoActionBar);
builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, android.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault_DialogWhenLarge);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this in your Style in your **values-v21/style.xml**

```html
<style name="AlertDialogCustom" parent="@android:style/Theme.Material.Dialog.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/cbt_ui_primary_dark</item>
        <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@style/DialogWindowTitle.Sphinx</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/cbt_hints_color</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowMinWidthMajor">@android:dimen/dialog_min_width_major</item>
        <item name="android:windowMinWidthMinor">@android:dimen/dialog_min_width_minor</item>
</style>
```

And for pre lollipop devices put it in **values/style.xml**

```html
<style name="AlertDialogCustom" parent="@android:style/Theme.Material.Dialog.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/cbt_ui_primary_dark</item>
        <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@style/DialogWindowTitle.Sphinx</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/cbt_hints_color</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowMinWidthMajor">@android:dimen/dialog_min_width_major</item>
        <item name="android:windowMinWidthMinor">@android:dimen/dialog_min_width_minor</item>
</style>

<style name="DialogWindowTitle.Sphinx" parent="@style/DialogWindowTitle_Holo">
       <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.Sphinx.DialogWindowTitle</item>
</style>

<style name="TextAppearance.Sphinx.DialogWindowTitle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.DialogWindowTitle">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/dark</item>
        <!--<item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-condensed</item>-->
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>
```