# Change dialog text color on 5.0+

Tags: android, dialog

I'm trying to change the text color in dialog boxes, most commonly AlertDialog.  I've tried every solution at these pages:

[AlertDialog styling - how to change style (color) of title, message, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16200914/alertdialog-styling-how-to-change-style-color-of-title-message-etc)

[How can I change the color of AlertDialog title and the color of the line under it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14439538/how-can-i-change-the-color-of-alertdialog-title-and-the-color-of-the-line-under)

[How to change theme for AlertDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422562/how-to-change-theme-for-alertdialog/5392617#5392617)

Most solutions work BELOW 5.0 but above it, and they don't seem to have any effect.  What different attributes should I be changing for 5.0+?

The parent theme of my app is "Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"

Answer (score 32):

In your case, I think the dialog theme would work.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity(), R.style.YourDialogStyle;
```

You can specify your dialog theme just like the code above.

```
<style name="YourDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/primary_dark</item>
</style>
```

Here is the example of theme for Dialog.

- **android:colorAccent** will affect your text colors of negative or positive buttons.
- **android:textColor** will affect your title text color of dialog.
- **android:textColorPrimary** will affect your message color of dialog.

Another option is you can make your own custom layout for the dialog.