# How to change textcolor in AlertDialog

Tags: android

[image: AlertDialog]

How to change the textcolor in an AlertDialog?

```
<item name="android:textColor">@color/black_text</item>
```

This changes the title color only.

```
ad = new AlertDialog.Builder((new ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.DialogTheme)));
            ad.setTitle(R.string.my_activ_remove_title_dialog);

            ad.setPositiveButton(R.string.my_activ_remove_dialog, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int arg1) {
                    content.remove(position);
                    notifyItemRemoved(position);
                    notifyItemRangeChanged(position, content.size());
                }

            });
            ad.setNegativeButton(R.string.my_activ_cancel_remove_dialog, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int arg1) {

                }
            });
```

[Alerd Dialog v2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwbNo.png)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

For changing the font color only, try this:

```
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#FF7F27'>This is a test</font>"));
    builder.setPositiveButton(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#FF7F27'>Yes</font>"), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int arg1) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Yes");
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#FF7F27'>No</font>"), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int arg1) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "No");
        }
    });
    builder.create();
    builder.show();
```

result:

[image]

---

For changing the font color and button background color, try this:

```
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#FF7F27'>This is a test</font>"));
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        }
    });
    builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        }
    });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
    Button nbutton = alert.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);
    //Set negative button background
    nbutton.setBackgroundColor(Color.MAGENTA);
    //Set negative button text color
    nbutton.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
    Button pbutton = alert.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
    //Set positive button background
    pbutton.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
    //Set positive button text color
    pbutton.setTextColor(Color.MAGENTA);
```

Result:

[image: Result:]

---

If you want to change divider color, try this:

```
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Test Title");
        builder.setMessage(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#FF7F27'>This is a test</font>"));
        builder.setCancelable(false);
        builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            }
        });
        builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            }
        });
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();
        try {
            Resources resources = dialog.getContext().getResources();
            int alertTitleId = resources.getIdentifier("alertTitle", "id", "android");
            TextView alertTitle = (TextView) dialog.getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(alertTitleId);
            alertTitle.setTextColor(Color.MAGENTA); // change title text color

            int titleDividerId = resources.getIdentifier("titleDivider", "id", "android");
            View titleDivider = dialog.getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(titleDividerId);
            titleDivider.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW); // change divider color
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        Button nbutton = dialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);
        //Set negative button background
        nbutton.setBackgroundColor(Color.MAGENTA);
        //Set negative button text color
        nbutton.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
        Button pbutton = dialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
        //Set positive button background
        pbutton.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
        //Set positive button text color
        pbutton.setTextColor(Color.MAGENTA);
```

This is my sample code, but if you want to change the divider color consider the part of the code starts with "int titleDividerId".

Result:

[image: This is the result of the code]

---

If you want to customize the AlertDialog a lot. For example adding some checkboxes with custom background color, use this approach:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        LinearLayout mainLayout       = new LinearLayout(this);
        mainLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        LinearLayout layout1       = new LinearLayout(this);
        layout1.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        CheckBox cb1 = new CheckBox(getApplicationContext());
        cb1.setText("Easy");
        layout1.addView(cb1);
        layout1.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        layout1.setMinimumHeight(50);

        LinearLayout layout2       = new LinearLayout(this);
        layout2.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        layout2.addView(new TextView(this));
        CheckBox cb2 = new CheckBox(getApplicationContext());
        cb2.setText("Normal");
        layout2.addView(cb2);
        layout2.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
        layout2.setMinimumHeight(50);

        LinearLayout layout3       = new LinearLayout(this);
        layout3.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        CheckBox cb3 = new CheckBox(getApplicationContext());
        cb3.setText("Hard");
        layout3.addView(cb3);
        layout3.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        layout3.setMinimumHeight(50);

        mainLayout.addView(layout1);
        mainLayout.addView(layout2);
        mainLayout.addView(layout3);
        alert.setTitle("Custom alert demo");
        alert.setView(mainLayout);
        alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        alert.setPositiveButton("Done", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        alert.show();
```

The result:

[image: The result]

Firstly, I created a main layout (vertical) as you see in the code. Then, for each one of the checkboxes I created a horizontal layout. In this case you can play with the colors and fonts of the elements (checkboxes, items, and etc.). I hope it helps.

Comment: AlertDialog alert = builder.create(); - builder can't resolv

Comment: First: AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this); then: AlertDialog alert = builder.create();

Comment: Do you have: "import android.app.AlertDialog;" in ur imports?

Comment: import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;

Comment: Change it to "import android.app.AlertDialog;". I mean delete that line and add this line instead.

Answer (score 10):

After you create your dialog:

```
AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
dialog.show();
Button buttonPositive = dialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
buttonPositive.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.green));
Button buttonNegative = dialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);
buttonNegative.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.red));
```

Comment: it works for me. but i have no idea why "builder.setPositiveButton(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#FF7F27'>Yes</font>"), ..." doesn't works for me

Comment: It worked for me to.. But remember you have to add dialog.show(); instead of builder.show(); then only it will work.

Comment: This should be the highest voted answer, not the whole HTML nonsense

Answer (score 5):

The text color is taken from the `colorAccent` value set in `styles.xml` (according to the style you set in your activity).

Answer (score 4):

Here are a few steps you can follow:

1.Add a style and name it whatever you want, in my case it's `AlertDialogTheme`

```
<style name="AlertDialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
</style>
```

2.Pass in your style as the second parameter on your `AlertDialog.Builder()` instance. Note that if you are creating the instance from an Activity, replace the first argument with `this`

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(requireActivity(), R.style.AlertDialogTheme);
```

3. View your changes

[image]

[image]

Comment: <item name="colorAccent">@color/teal_200</item>
<item name="android:textColor">@color/teal_200</item>
... Works for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For 'Material Design' alert dialog:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="MaterialAlertDialog.MaterialComponents">
    <item name="materialAlertDialogTitleTextStyle">@style/AlertDialogTitleText</item>
    <item name="materialAlertDialogBodyTextStyle">@style/AlertDialogBodyText</item>
</style>

<style name="AlertDialogTitleText" parent="MaterialAlertDialog.MaterialComponents.Title.Text">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
</style>

<style name="AlertDialogBodyText" parent="MaterialAlertDialog.MaterialComponents.Body.Text">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

The dialog should be built with the Material builder and the style needs to be set.

```
new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(getContext(), R.style.MyTheme)
            .setTitle("Title")
            .setMessage("Message");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     alertDialog.setOnShowListener(OnShowListener { dialog -> 

        val buttonPositive: Button = alertDialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE)
        buttonPositive.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(), R.color.orange_strong))

        val buttonNegative: Button = alertDialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE)
        buttonNegative.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(), R.color.orange_strong))

    })

    // show alert dialog
    alertDialog.show()
```