# change standard checkbox color in setmultichoiceitems

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, multichoiceitems

I have a alertdialog which contains multichoice items and all other functionality is working fine. I've a problem with the color of the checkbox it is showing is not matching with my app color. I've tried with the setcustombuilder but it is not working. Please help. I dont want to use listview.

```
final String[] ratings = {"2015","2016"};
final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
final boolean[] ratingschecked = {false,false};
 builder.setTitle("Select Year");
    builder.setMultiChoiceItems(ratings, ratingschecked, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {
           //something
        }
    }).setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            //something
        }
    }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        }
    });

    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    builder.show();
```

is there any possibilties to change the color of android checkbox color to other?

### Answer:

```
 Created a Style file.
         <style name="AppCompatAlertDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
          <item name="colorAccent">@color/brand</item>
         </style>
```

Then add this file in the App theme. It works.

```
         <item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/AppCompatAlertDialogStyle</item>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this line in your theme in styles.xml

```
<style>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@android:color/holo_green_dark</item>
</style>
```

with color of your choice

Comment: My Target API is 23. It is not supported here.please help

Comment: Tried <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>  but not working

Answer (score 1):

In this link I showed how to change standard checkbox color in multichoiceitems. It also shows how to customize the AletDialog. For example, how to change divider colro and etc. Please visit this link:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33439849/5475941.

I hope it helps.