# Is it possible to change text colour of a string in Java?

Tags: java, android, html

I want to know if it is possible to change text colour within strings in Java?

I have a peice of text below within my alert dialog and basically what I like is for all the text that are in bold (), I want the colour of those text to be red whilst the rest of the text is black. Is this possible and if so how to implement?

```
    alertDialog.setMessage(Html.fromHtml("<b>Number of Human Players Required:</b>" + "<br/><br/>" +
 " 2" + "<br/><br/>" +
  "<b>Objective Of The Game:</b>" + "<br/><br/>" +
 "The objective of Tic Tac Toe is to get three in a row either in a vertical line, " +
                                    "horizontal line or diagonal line."

    )
```

Thanks,

Comment: Note that his is not Java-specific, but actually HTML + CSS.

Comment: as luk said, its html + css specific. try this
<b style="color:red;">your stuff here </b>

Comment: for change color font form html in android try this answer => https://stackoverflow.com/a/33439849/6364902

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
String s =  "<font color='red'><b>Number of Human Players Required:</b></font>" 
            + "<br/><br/>" + " 2" + "<br/><br/>" 
            + "<font color='blue'><b>Objective Of The Game:</b></font>" 
            + "<br/><br/>" 
            + "<font color='yellow'>The objective of Tic Tac Toe is to get three in a row either in a vertical line, " 
            + "horizontal line or diagonal line.</font>"

alertDialog.setMessage(Html.fromHtml(s));
```