# How to change TextInput Layout Cursor bottom bubble colour in Android?

Tags: android

Am using TextInputLayout. in that my cursor bottom bubble colour is in dark violet but I need it as white. I tried to change accent colour in theme but it donesn't work. And also am using Backpressed method for exit alert dialog. In that my positive and negative buttons also in violet colour but i need it as black. How can i achieve this?
Refer my snap.
[image: Cursor]
[image: Alert]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cursor color is based on the primary color of the app.
You will need to create a style sheet and add it to your TextInputLayout view.
You can override the app's primary color in this way -
[a] If you want to change only cursor color-
Use -

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout                
style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppTheme.TextInputEditText.Outlined"
....>
```

with the style.xml file -

```
<style name="ThemeOverlay.AppTheme.TextInputEditText.Outlined" parent="">
<item name="colorControlActivated">@color/...</item>
```

[b] If you want to change the color of your EditText and Cursor both -

with this style.xml file -

```
<style name="ThemeOverlay.AppTheme.TextInputEditText.Outlined" parent="">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/red</item>
</style>
```

[image]

Comment: It's not working. If I give theme as you given in Layout it's outline property is gone.

Comment: I've added the screenshot do check out that. Also if not working can you please provide your layout file code.

Comment: Thanks dude it's working great. In previous I made a mistake. How can i change the colour in my exit alert box?

Comment: @Gokul You can update your style.xml file with this `<style name="ThemeOverlay.AppTheme.TextInputEditText.Outlined" parent="">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/red</item>
    </style>` Check out the updated answer.

Comment: I think you didn't get me. Cursor colour problem is solved. Refer second image. In that i need to change the Yes and No button's colour into black.

Comment: I guess they depend on app's primaryColor try changing the primary color in your colors.xml file.

Comment: No dude it's not working. I tried with Primary colour and PrimaryDark also. But got same result

Comment: @Gokul Maybe this will help https://stackoverflow.com/a/33439849/9129342

Comment: Found a solution of it.  Button positive = alertDialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
        positive.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        Button negative = alertDialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);
        negative.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);