# Android alert dialog text is not visible

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-dialogfragment, android-styles, android-background

Hi I am using custom theme to customize my alert dialog.My problem is when ever i set background color to any color my texts become invisible.Here is my code

```
<style name="CustomDialogFragment" parent="android:Theme.Dialog">

        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/black</item>
        <item name="textColorAlertDialogListItem">@color/white</item>

    </style>
```

any help will be appreciated and thanks in advance

Comment: Just add `<item name="android:textColor">#54D66A</item>`

Comment: set white color for text <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>

Comment: still texts are invisible

Comment: change the background color to <item name="android:background">@color/lightGreay</item> and check.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set

```
<item name="android:textColor">#54D66A</item> // Add your Hex color code
```

**Edit**

You should use `android:textColorPrimary`

```
<item name="android:textColorPrimary">#54D66A</item>
```

Comment: @Karthik http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16200914/alertdialog-styling-how-to-change-style-color-of-title-message-etc

Comment: @Karthik what was the problem?

Comment: I replaced textColor with textColorPrimary @ IntelliJ Amiya

Answer (score 1):

You have to set color for your text bec yoyr dialog background color and text color is same so text is not visible, set

```
<item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
```

Comment: add `<item name="android:textColorPrimary">#Your_Hex_Code</item>`

Answer (score 1):

```
        <item name="textColorPrimary">@color/primary_text_dark</item>
```

try this

[Guide Line](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/values/themes.xml)

Answer (score 0):

try the below style accordingly:

```
<style name="AlertDialogCustom" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColorAlertDialogListItem">#FFFFFF</item>
</style>
```

Comment: still texts are invisible

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by applying theme to your dialog.

Use **android.R.style.Theme_Material_Light_Dialog_Alert** as your dialog theme. like this

```
builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext, android.R.style.Theme_Material_Light_Dialog_Alert);
```

Hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
    <style name="CustomDialogFragment"   parent="@android:style/android:Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:textColor">#00FF00</item>
    <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">10sp</item>
    </style>
    </resources>
```

i think it will be help you..

Answer (score 0):

For Android N support you should use :

```
<item name="android:textColorPrimary">#ffffff</item>
<item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light.Dialog.Alert</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the reason is because using the "wrong" layout inflater. Spend the whole day to solve this issue :(

"Wrong" Inflater

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) Navigations.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

"Correct" Inflater

```
LayoutInflater inflater = mainActivity.getLayoutInflater();
```