# MainActivity: change Dialog text color

Tags: android, kotlin

everyone. Please, how can I change the color of my dialog text? I have succeeded in changing the background color to black, so I want to change the text to white. Below is my code:

```
fun notificationofWinner(player: Int) {
        val alert = AlertDialog.Builder(this@MainActivity, R.style.MyDialogTheme)
        alert.setTitle("GAME OVER! Player $player wins!!!")
        alert.setPositiveButton("Ok") { dialog , Button -> }
        alert.show()
    }
```

Comment: Please share your `MyDialogTheme`

Answer (score 0):

In your style `R.style.MyDialogTheme`

Add your `textColor` or a whole `textStyle`.

This answer should get you started

[AlertDialog styling - how to change style (color) of title, message, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16200914/alertdialog-styling-how-to-change-style-color-of-title-message-etc)

My personal preference is to make a `DialogFragment` instead as you will get a lot more freedom out of using it than the basic `AlertDialog`.

Comment: Thank you for kind response.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change in your style,
you can do it with Html like...
`alert.setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#ffffff'>GAME OVER! Player $player wins!!</font>"))`

Answer (score 0):

If you want the full control over the appearance of a dialog box, you should consider making a custom dialog box like this.

```js
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
```

where `custom_dialog` is your custom dialog layout file. Customise as however you want.

Use `dialog.show()` whenever you want to show the dialog and to hide, use `dialog.hide()` or `dialog.dismiss()`